# How can I combine tabular results and json representation of the row as a column in a single query?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

The sql server json capabilities for querying json in t-sql and returning an entire result set as json are great but I'm looking for a 'mixed-mode' approach where I want to specify a set of columns for the result set but then also want the entire row to be converted to a json object/column.

Something like this:

```
select ProductId, Name, Category, ProductJson = (* for json auto) 
from Product
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ProductId, Name, Category,
  [JSON] = (SELECT * FROM dbo.Product WHERE ProductID = p.ProductID FOR JSON AUTO) 
FROM dbo.Product AS p;
```

Or `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT p.ProductId, p.Name, p.Category, j.son
  FROM dbo.Product AS p 
  CROSS APPLY 
  (SELECT * FROM dbo.Product WHERE ProductID = p.ProductID FOR JSON AUTO) AS j(son);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Don't love it but seems to be the simple path for now.